# Jaspersoft Report - net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpressionEvalException: Error evaluating expression

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am using TIBCO Jaspersoft Studio-6.1.1.final.

I have a report which is having java jar file added in scriptlet to read doc file.

When I run in Jasper report I am getting below error.

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpressionEvalException: Error evaluating expression for source text: $P{Read_DocFile_SCRIPTLET}.readline()
at com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.preview.view.control.ReportControler.fillReport(ReportControler.java:511)
at com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.preview.view.control.ReportControler.access$20(ReportControler.java:486)
at com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.preview.view.control.ReportControler$5.run(ReportControler.java:367)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpressionEvalException: Error evaluating expression for source text: $P{Read_DocFile_SCRIPTLET}.readline()
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JREvaluator.evaluate(JREvaluator.java:291)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRCalculator.evaluate(JRCalculator.java:618)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRCalculator.evaluate(JRCalculator.java:586)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElement.evaluateExpression(JRFillElement.java:1015)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillTextField.evaluateText(JRFillTextField.java:568)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillTextField.evaluate(JRFillTextField.java:552)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.evaluate(JRFillElementContainer.java:281)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.evaluate(JRFillBand.java:504)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillColumnBand(JRVerticalFiller.java:2029)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillDetail(JRVerticalFiller.java:755)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:262)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:122)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:555)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseFillHandle$ReportFill.run(BaseFillHandle.java:119)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.POIDocument: method <init>()V not found
    at org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocument.<init>(HWPFDocument.java:144)
    at org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocument.<init>(HWPFDocument.java:133)
    at com.Read_DocFile.readline(Read_DocFile.java:25)
    at Blank_
```

Java file having two external jar file, which I added into lib folder and generated jar file in Eclipse.

Java code added below

```
package com;

import java.io.*;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.extractor.WordExtractor;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRDefaultScriptlet;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRScriptletException;

public class ReadDocFile extends JRDefaultScriptlet {

  public String readline() throws JRScriptletException {
    File file = null;
    WordExtractor extractor = null;
    try {
      file = new File("C:\\Tempp\\RTF_view.doc");
      FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());
      HWPFDocument document = new HWPFDocument(fis);
      extractor = new WordExtractor(document);
      String[] fileData = extractor.getParagraphText();
      for (int i = 0; i < fileData.length; i++) {
        if (fileData[i] != null)
          return fileData[i];     
      }
    } catch (Exception exep) {
        exep.printStackTrace();
    }   
    return "Hello! I'm the report's scriptlet object.";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in your stacktrace

```
com.Read_DocFile.readline(Read_DocFile.java:25)

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.POIDocument: method <init>()V not found
```

If you have no error in your IDE, make sure that you have same version of class library (POI) deployed where you run the report.

**Problem:** probably different versions of poi library (or multiple POI with different version in classpath)

**Solution:** use same version

Where the heck is it loading the POI classes?

```
ClassLoader classloader =
   org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem.class.getClassLoader();
URL res = classloader.getResource(
         "org/apache/poi/poifs/filesystem/POIFSFileSystem.class");
String path = res.getPath();
System.out.println("Core POI came from " + path);
```

Comment: I added same jar file into lib folder in Eclipse and then generated Read_DocFile jar file. I added this jar file to jasper report scriptlets . Below is my jasper code.  <detail>
  <band height="125" splitType="Stretch">
   <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
    <reportElement x="100" y="30" width="360" height="50" uuid="ada6cef7-5b57-4439-bd85-eba1b787ae52"/>
    <textElement markup=""/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{Read_DocFile_SCRIPTLET}.readline()]]></textFieldExpression>
   </textField>
  </band>
 </detail>

Comment: Watch out you have now probably two copies of POI in your classpath, change the catch (Exception exep) to catch (Throwable exep) and you will see that its not a problem of your report..., but classpath problem...

Comment: I have added some code (see edit of answer, where the heck) so you can check it out....

Comment: I added your code to java class. But try catch block not executing .

Comment: and do you still have     at org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocument.<init>(HWPFDocument.java:144) or another error?

Comment: Now no error is coming. Only last return statement is executing and printing in jasper report.

Comment: Exactly so jasper now works but you method goes in error but you are catching the error with throwable,  so this is a test that you have no problem with jasper!, what you need now is to serach for the duplicated jar (tell me what System.out.println("Core POI came from " + path); @see answer says